# Azure Dev Ops on Premise

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

We have a server where we have installed Azure Dev Ops, we do not use any remote directories for handling repos. Everything is done on that one server.

We have created a project on C:/WorkSpace folder on the server. The project is added to visual studio source control.

The server is accessed via RDP by three developers and they work on the visual studio which is installed on the server. Each developer uses his or her credentials to login to the server via RDP. We have created three branches from the main project. Our structure looks like below:

- IP Address\DefaultCollection

  - Project Name

    - Dev1Branch
    - Dev2Branch
    - Dev3Branch
    - MainBranch

When a developer needs to work she merges MainBranch into her branch and then works on her branch. When work is completed she commits her branch and then merges it to MainBranch and then does a final commit on MainBranch.

Is the above structure fine or are we missing something?

The issue that we are having is that one when developer is working on a file, her and second developer is working on the same file as well then Developer 1 excludes that file from checking in. If any changes are made in future then these excluded files are not being tracked.

Comment: **Why** are people logging in to your application tier server to work? There's no need for that. They can connect to the server from their computers and map a workspace. And if two people are working on a file at the same time, **that's fine**. They should just work on it, check it in when they're done, and if there are conflicting changes, they'll have to merge it. There is zero reason to be excluding files.

Comment: What is your source control type? TFVC, or Git? As you describe, it look like Git, but you add a TFVC tag in this ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the anomaly. I was using TFVC so I changed the project type to Git and the visual studio prompted me to install 3rd party Git which I did. It is working fine now.